# SSAS: Number of occurences based on the measure value

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a SSAS multidimensionnal project for a cube that contains data about vehicule speeds and accelerations.

My fact table ([trucks].[FactSpeed]) has the following columns

- DateKey (Date Dimension)
- MachineKey  (Machine Dimension)
- OperatorKey (Operator Dimension)
- Timetag (Date and Time of the reading)
- Speed (Speedometer reading)
- Acceleration (Accelerometer reading)
- Other measures

I managed to calculate the number of speed occurences above 100 km/h by using a Speed dimension which have values between 0 km/h and 255 km/h

```
 SELECT NON EMPTY{ 
[Measures].[Speed Occurence],
[Measures].[Speed Distance Kilometers],
[Measures].[Speed Duration Hours]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Truck]
WHERE ( [Date].[Day].&[2017-07-11T00:00:00],
[Machines].[MachineKey].&[52], 
[Operators].[OperatorKey].&[124],
[Speed].[Speed Key].&[100] : null)
```

I am not sure if this is the best technique to do this. Im trying to do the same thing with the acceleration measure. Unfortunatly, the reading is a real datatype and I have over 24 000 different values for the acceleration.

**My question is**: Is it possible to calculate the number of acceleration occurences above a threshold by using a MDX query that will return the same result as the query below?:

```
select count(*) from [trucks].[FactSpeed] where datekey >= '2017-07-11' and datekey < '2017-07-12' and machinekey = 52 and  operatorkey = 124 and acceleration >= 1
```